# read headers in html page with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, header

i want to read specific headers for current html page, this code below read all headers, how i can read a specific header having the tag?

```
   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   req.open('GET', document.location, false);
   req.send(null);
   var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
   alert(headers);
```

This code return this result: 
date: mon, 11 may...
last-modified: mon, 11 m...
accept range: bytes ...etc..

is there a method to read a specific field in headers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `getResponseHeader` instead of `getAllResponseHeaders` to extract a specific header :

```
var header = req.getResponseHeader('last-modified');
```

Comment: thx its working, but if the page looks like index.html?name=malo how can i read name?    var header = req.getResponseHeader('name'); i tried this but not working

Comment: GET arguments are not part of the headers. You should take a look in here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter and use his function QueryString to extract them as an Object :)